# Making a dynamic drop down menu sticky in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I have a dynamic drop down menu on a PHP form which is working fine in that it retrieves/inputs the right id and will not process the form if no option is collected.

However, I am not sure how to make it sticky. I can do it on a static drop down with no problems but obviously I am missing something, can anyone help?

Below is the drop down menu:

```
echo '<div align="left">
<select name="dealership_id">
<option value="NULL">Choose a Dealer:</option>'; 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM dealership ORDER BY users_dealer_name ASC';
$result = mysql_query ($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
echo "<option value=\"$row[0] \" <?php if (isset($_POST['dealership_id']) && $_POST['dealership_id'] == '$row[0]') {echo 'selected=\"selected\"';} ?> >$row[3]</option>";
}
// Complete the dropdown
echo '</select> 
</div>
';
```

Below is the validation code

```
if (isset($_POST['dealership_id'])) {
$dealer_id = (int) $_POST['dealership_id'];
} else {
$dealer_id = 0;
}
if ($dealer_id > 0) {
$query = "SELECT dealership_id FROM dealership WHERE dealership_id=$dealer_id";
$result = mysql_query ($query); }
else {
echo '<p><font color="red">Please select your Dealership</font></p>'; 
}
```

BTW, row 0 is the primary key, row 3 is the name.

Comment: Sticky? Like position: fixed?

Comment: No, when the user fills in the form on their browser, and misses a compulsory field and the form does not complete. So when they fill in the form above, the form does not submit but shows the error message. However rather than keep the drop down option they have that is selected, it reverts to the "Choose A Dealer" option.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a stickiness problem. That sounds like a php problem.

Comment: We need teh moar coadz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there should be single quotes around `$row[0]` in the following:

```
$_POST['dealership_id'] == '$row[0]'
```

By using single quotes you are literally comparing the string $row[0] instead of the variable value

Here's your code with some changes that are at least valid syntax; I didn't test to see if it works, but it should. It would be helpful for you to research string concatenation in php, some useful info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
echo '<div align="left">
<select name="dealership_id">
<option value="NULL">Choose a Dealer:</option>'; 

$query = 'SELECT * FROM dealership ORDER BY users_dealer_name ASC';
$result = mysql_query ($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo "<option value=\"$row[0]\"";
    if (isset($_POST['dealership_id']) && $_POST['dealership_id'] == $row[0]){
        echo ' selected=\"selected\"';
    }
    echo ">$row[3]</option>";
}
// Complete the dropdown
echo '</select> 
</div>
';
```

Comment: Also may try removing the <?php tags that are nested inside your <option> tag - its hard to tell from your snippet, but it looks like the whole thing is in a parse-able code block, so you wouldn't nest tags like that without breaking out of <?php first.

Comment: Nothing again, Im not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It worked! Thank you @Jason Fingar. I almost gave up and was going to type in 90 rows manually, you've saved me a lot of time and I can't thank you enough!